# What is the NUnit framework lifecycle execution order?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, nunit

Recently, I added a test project in my ASP.NET MVC project which is based on NUnit Framework (Version 3.7.1.0). I know that there are some attributes in NUnit as well as the other frameworks that we can add them to our class and methods in order to write better Tests cases.

Here are the attributes which introduced by the NUnit documentation:

- SetUp
- TearDown
- TestFixtureSetUp
- TestFixtureTearDown

I'd like to know the execution order and performance consideration behind the scenes for implementing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know the execution order

Setup/TearDown methods related to `TestFixture` will be executed only once for TestFixture. Setup/TearDown methods related to `Test` will be executed **for each** test. Here is the order with a loop in the middle:

```
TestFixtureSetUp    // executed once before first test SetUp
   SetUp            // excuted before *each* test
   TearDown         // executed after *each* test
TestFixtureTearDown // executed once after last test TearDown
```

I use `SetUp` method to move there code which is repeated in the *arrange* part of the test. Usually you intialize SUT in `SetUp` method by creating it and providing required mocked dependencies.

`TestFixtureSetUp` is more global - it prepares battleground for all tests in the fixture. Usually, I use it to initialize some environment - e.g. create a database and/or setup tables with some initial data. `TestFixtureTearDown` is used to drop that database. Of course, environment initialization is not related to unit tests - it's for acceptance tests.

> performance consideration behind the scenes for implementing that

Same as for any other method calls. It depends on you what to put into setup or teardown methods.

Comment: Note that `TestFixtureSetUp` and `TestFixtureTearDown` are deprecated in NUnit 3, in favor of `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown`.